# Missing Ethernet Adapter in ipconfig with VirtualBox

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, virtualbox, samba

I have two web development environments, one on a laptop and one on a desktop.

I have setup my laptop to use DHCP but also to maintain a static IP so that I can consistently connect to Samba with the same IP address.

This is the routing table on both the laptop and desktop. Both are connected to the same Wireless network.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway     Genmask        Flags    Metric    Ref    Use    Iface
10.0.0.0       *           255.255.255.0  U        0         0      0      eth1
10.0.2.0       *           255.255.255.0  U        0         0      0      eth0
169.254.0.0    *           255.255.0.0    U        0         0      0      eth1
default        10.0.2.2    0.0.0.0        UG       0         0      0      eth0
```

My laptop is the machine that works. and it shows this under an `ipconfig` in Windows:

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:

IPv4 Address : 10.0.0.1
Subnet Mask  : 255.255.255.0
```

For some reason I have no such option on the desktop machine, despite having the *exact* same devices setup (an eth0 and eth1).

So to summarise, I can't access my dev environment on my desktop via Windows (whereas I can on my laptop) even although the configuration looks identical to me.

A `ping www.development-environment.com` works on the desktop, but I can't access it through the browser.

Comment: note that windows hides unconfigured and disabled nics from ipconfig unless you use the /all switch.

Comment: I can't understand what parts of your question describe the hosts and what describe the guests. The routing table is from a guest? The ipconfig output is from a host? When you're pinging, where are your running the ping and what is the target? Please go back through your question and add some more detail. While you're at it, please describe  how many network adapters you've set up on each guest (two?) and what network types each one is configured for.

Answer (score 0):

The network probably needs to be configured in the /etc/network/interfaces file. Presuming your network interface is named eth0, and presuming your LAN has a functioning DHCP server, the following entry in your guest's interfaces file should do the trick:
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp